# ¿Cómo pasar un parámetro que está en la misma clase?

Tags: php, poo, php7

Estoy aprendiendo y acostumbrándome a la POO de PHP7. En este momento, quisiera subir a una base de datos, unas variables que corresponden a una imagen, el título de esa imagen y la descripción para que se suba a un carrusel. Así lo estoy intentando:

```
<?php

//Se inicia la conexión a la base de datos.
include('conexion.php');

//Se inician las funciones.
include('funciones.php');

//Si existen datos, hacer...
if (isset($_POST['imagen_slider']) && isset($_POST['titulo_carrusel']) && isset($_POST['descripcion_slider']) && isset($_POST['subir_slide'])) {

    //Se reciben los datos y se guardan en variables.
    $ruta=$_POST['imagen_slider'];
    $titulo=$_POST['titulo_carrusel'];
    $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion_slider'];

    //Se crea una nueva instancia.
    $slider=new subirFotos();

    //Se envía la variable de conexión a la función de validación del ID.
    $slider->validarID($mysqli);
    $slider->registrarSlide($id, $ruta, $titulo, $descripcion);

}

?>
```

Esta es la clase que estoy utilizando:

```
<?php

/**
  * Clase que toma las nuevas fotos para el slider
*/
class subirFotos
{

    public function validarID($mysqli){

        $id=0;

        //Se consigue el valor máximo del ID.
        $consultar_id=$mysqli->query("SELECT id_slider FROM slider WHERE id_slider=(SELECT MAX(id_slider) FROM slider)");

        //Se crea y recorre el arreglo.
        while ($i=mysqli_fetch_array($consultar_id)) {

            $id=$i['id_slider']+1;
            return $id;

        }

    }

    public function registrarSlide($id, $ruta, $titulo, $descripcion)
    {
        echo $id;
    }

}

?>
```

Quisiera que la variable que estoy creando, a través de la función `validarID()`, se pase a la función `registrarSlide()` y aún así, me permita enviar las variables que recibo por el método POST.

Comment: Acabo de intentar cambiar el return por global y ya me entra a la función, pero la variable $id no tiene valor.

Comment: A la variable que te refieres es '$id'?

Comment: Sí. La variable que necesito es $id. Se crea un la primera función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu variable `$id` debería existir a nivel del *scope* o contexto de la clase como una propiedad y no solo dentro del método `validarId()` como variable de este modo:

```
class subirFotos
{
    public  $id=0;
}
```

De modo tal que cuando invoques ahora a esta *propiedad* dentro de los métodos lo puedas hacer así:

```
public function validarID()
{
    $this->id;
}
```

Considero que no lo debes pasar como argumento del método, pues ya dentro de la propia clase le estas asignando un valor por defecto que es 0, por lo tanto si tu lo indicas como argumento de dicho método, te va a ser requerido al momento de crear la instancia y te lanzaría un error como este:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function subirFotos::validarID(),

Y con la misma sintaxis del método anterior ya pudieras usar dicha *propiedad* en cualquier método de la clase `subirFotos`

Comment: ¡Bien! Ya entendí. Muchas gracias. Considero que aprendo más rápido con la práctica y es una buena forma de aprender el $this->. Sirvió correctamente. Muchas gracias.